# Ada - Commando- line reader and processer

Tags: command, ada

A program that loads and processes command-line arguments should be created.

Here comes a few examples on how it should look when you run it (bold text is the text that the user will type):

```
Terminal prompt % **./my_program**

No arguments given.

Terminal prompt % **./my_program 123**

Wrong amounts of arguments given.

Terminal prompt % **./my_program 10 XYZ 999 Greetings!**


Wrong amounts of arguments given.

Terminal prompt % **./my_program 3 HELLO**

Message: HELLOHELLOHELLO

The program "./my program" is ending.

Terminal prompt % **./my_program 0 Bye**

Message:

The program "./my program" is ending.
```

This is my code so far:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line;    use Ada.Command_Line;

procedure my_program is 
   
    type String is array (Positive) of Character;
 
    N : Integer;
    Text : String;
   
begin
   
    N := Argument_Count;

    if N = 0 then
        Put_Line("No arguments given.");
    elsif N /= 2 then 
        Put_Line("Wrong number of arguments given.");
    elsif N = 2 then
        Put("Message: ");

        for I in 1 .. N loop
            Put(Text);
            New_Line;
        end loop;
      
        Put("The program """);
        Put(""" is ending. ");
    end if;
   
 end my_program;
```

My program handles the first 3 three cases but when I go ahead with the 4th and 5th (last) case I get an error code at the row **Put(Text**) where it says

> Missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "Put"

I don't know if I declared my string right because I don't want a string of a specific length. Can anyone come up with something that could help me solve case 4 and 5? It would be nice and highly appreciated

Comment: Please note that when you call `Put(Text)`, `Text` has not been initialized. Did you mean to use `Put(Argument(I));`?

Comment: Hmm I dont really know what you mean. So I have N integer so when one for instance types "5 Hi" its supposed to type "Hi" five times (HiHiHiHiHi). This is what ive been trying to do with my loop. Or should I do Get_Line? I dont really know

Comment: Then you need to get the integer value of the first argument, and print the second argument that many times. Your existing code doesn't even attempt to do those things.

Comment: Another immediate problem is your declaration `type String is array (Positive) of Character;` creates a new String type, so that Text is of the new type, which effectively has no "Put" method. Comment that out and `With` / `Use Ada.Strings;` instead. `Ada.Text_IO` already supplies I/O methods for that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a homework or exam question, so I would usually not provide a full answer. But Chris already gave that (with some defects), so here is my suggestion. Compared to Chris's solution, I try to avoid using unnecessary variables, and I favour case statements over if-then-else cascades, and I try to reduce the scope of exception handlers. I prefer to put use clauses in the subprogram so that the context-clause section contains only with clauses. I use the string-multiplying "*" operator from Ada.Strings.Fixed, but that is perhaps an unnecessary refinement.

```
with Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure My_Program
is
   use Ada.Strings.Fixed;
   use Ada.Text_IO;
begin

   case Ada.Command_Line.Argument_Count is

   when 0 =>
      Put_Line ("No arguments given.");

   when 2 =>
      begin
         Put_Line (
              Natural'Value (Ada.Command_Line.Argument(1))
            * Ada.Command_Line.Argument(2));
      exception
         when Constraint_Error =>
            Put_Line ("Invalid input for argument 1.");
      end;

   when others =>
      Put_Line ("Wrong amount of arguments given.");

   end case;

   Put_Line (
        "The program """
      & Ada.Command_Line.Command_Name
      & """ is ending.");

end My_Program;
```

Note that my version:

- Rejects negative first arguments (like "-3").
- Outputs the repeated strings on a single line, as was required by the examples given.
- Includes the name of the program in the final message, as was also required.

Answer (score 0):

Given the clarification in comments as to the purpose of the program, to print a message `n` times where `n` is the first argument, and the message is the second argument, you need to parse the first argument as an integer. This can be done with `Integer'Value`.

Now, that raises the prospect of the user not running the program with an integer. So we have to handle the possible `Constraint_Error` exception.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line;    use Ada.Command_Line;

procedure my_program is

    argc : Integer;
    N : Integer;

begin

    argc := Argument_Count;

    if argc = 0 then
        Put_Line("No arguments given.");
    elsif argc /= 2 then
        Put_Line("Wrong number of arguments given.");
    else
        n := Integer'Value(Argument(1));

        Put("Message: ");

        for I in 1 .. N loop
            Put_Line(Argument(2));
        end loop;

        Put("The program """);
        Put(""" is ending. ");
    end if;

exception

    when Constraint_Error =>
        Put_Line("Invalid input for argument 1.");

end my_program;
```

As an aside, when we've checked in our conditional if `argc` is zero, and that it doesn't equal two, we don't have to use `elsif`. The only other possibility is that it *is* `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> My program handles the first 3 three cases but when I go ahead with the 4th and 5th (last) case I get an error code at the row Put(Text) where it says "Missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "Put". "

which doesn't make sense, because your program as shown doesn't compile. I guess what you mean is "when I try to add the code to handle cases 4 and 5, it doesn't compile".

The reason why it doesn’t compile is hidden in the actual error messages:

```
leun.adb:24:10: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
leun.adb:24:10: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "put" declared at a-tiinio.ads:97, instance at a-inteio.ads:18
...
leun.adb:24:14: expected type "Standard.Integer"
leun.adb:24:14: found type "String" defined at line 7
leun.adb:24:14:   ==> in call to "Put" at a-tiinio.ads:80, instance at a-inteio.
```

You have at line 7

```
   type String is array (Positive) of Character;
```

which is both misleading and not what you meant.

It’s ’not what you meant’ because `array (Positive)` means an array of fixed length from 1 to `Positive’Last`, which will not fit into your computer’s memory. What you meant is `array (Positive range <>)`.

Even with this correction, it's 'misleading' because although it would be *textually* the same as the declaration of the standard `String` in [ARM 3.6.3(4)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-6-3.html), in Ada two different type declarations declare two different types. So, when you write `Put(Text);` the `Put` that you meant to call (the second in [ARM A.10.7(16)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-6-3.html)) doesn’t match because it’s expecting a parameter of type `Standard.String` but `Text` is of type `my_program.String`.

---

Cure for this problem: don’t declare your own `String` type.

Comment: Nitpick: With some Ada compilers, an array (Positive) of Character may fit in the computer's memory, because Positive'Last may be as small as 32767 (when the compiler has a 16-bit Integer type).

Comment: @NiklasHolsti: yes, but considering the OP’s starting point that would be unlikely!